# Use assets from gem in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am trying to figure out how to get boostrap-sass working in production mode. I am using apache to reverse proxy to either webrick or puma, but serve the static assets in public/assets directly. When I precompile assets, the bootstrap css gets included into the application-(hash).css and it works correctly.

However the compiled css references an image file (glyphicons-halfling.png) without appending the hash of the file contents. The image file is included in public/assets directory, and it is possible to browse to it by putting the correct filename in the address bar, but the filename in the css does not match it. I have created a simple demo app that demonstrates this problem, code is on my [github page](https://github.com/slicedpan/RailsTest)

The glyphicon filename is `glyphicons-halflings-c806376f05e4ccabe2c5315a8e95667c.png`

[EDIT]

Would still like an answer to this question, but i've just renamed the offending files to remove the hash. Since these files are unlikely to change frequently then this should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have it cracked, when you run rake assets:precompile, it seems that you must prefix it with RAILS_ENV=production in order for it to work properly in production mode (I guess that kind of makes sense). If you don't, some of your assets will get precompiled, but the helper methods will not generate the correct paths.

tl:dr, `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`